# Resize UICollectionViewCell with UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiviewanimation

I'm, animating a change of the frame of a `UICollectionView` and I'd like the cells (which are set to the `size.width` and `size.height` of the `collectionView`) to animate a frame change along with them... however they remain their original size and the `collectionView` animates fine... what am I missing?

```
func goFullscreen() {

    setForTransition() // removes old constraints on collectionView
    applyFullscreenConstraints() // sets new constraints on the collectionView

    collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()

    setNeedsLayout()

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0.01, options: [.beginFromCurrentState,.curveEaseInOut], animations: {

        self.layoutIfNeeded()

    }, completion: { (finished) in })
}
```

Comment: That's not quite how collection views work. You say you're setting the cells to `size.width` and `size.height` of the collection view itself? So you are only showing **one** cell at a time? Maybe `UICollectionView` isn't the right tool for this task?

Comment: Yes I'm sure a `UICollectionView` is the right tool for the task... *eyeroll*

Comment: OK... If you are sizing the cells to the size of the collection view, that means you are only showing ONE cell at a time. Why is collection view better than, for example, `UIPageViewController` for your particular task? Or... am I reading your question incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your collection size in this method

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

```
        return CGSize.init(width: self.view.bounds.size.width/2-12, height: 120)
}
```

give your height and width in this method.

Comment: have you created xib for collectionview cell or working with collectionview cell inside collectionview

Comment: can u attach screen shot of storyboard?

Answer (score -1):

You can resize all the `visibleCells` with a `performBatchUpdates`:

```
collectionView.performBatchUpdates({ () -> Void in       
    // Resize your cells
    for (let cell : UICollectionViewCell in collectionView.visibleCells) {
        cell.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)
    }
}, completion: nil)
```

This code is just a draft (not tested)

Comment: I mean, this is just garbage... even if `performbatchupdates` is the way forward this code is crap.

Comment: Except it works independently from me animating the `collectionView` at it's own duration and animation curve

Comment: And I'd expect you to write code that compiles. Writing 'This code is just a draft (not tested)` isn't an acceptable excuse. Otherwise you can just write `collectionView.performBatchUpdates` which still doesn't help me resize `UICollectionViewCells` **with** `UICollectionView`

Comment: I just suggest you a quick solution to animate your resize.. So you can watch out and try to work with. I'm just trying to help you guy